# How to reset page zoom to 100% in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

There is an aura component that should always render at 100% zoom level of browser. If user increase the zoom level to 125% it should automatically set the zoom level 100% and show the component according to this zoom level.

I have tried `load` and `resize` events in `init`, `render`, `rerender` and `afterRender` and it sets the `window.devicePixelRatio` but the changes not get reflected on component:

Example code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if ( Math.round( window.devicePixelRatio * 100 ) == 125 ) {
    window.devicePixelRatio = 1;
  }
}
```

and I have tried same piece of code without `load` and `resize` events.

So, my question is how I can re-render the component after changing the `window.devicePixelRatio` value to `1` i.e., 100%.

Thank you!